# Dynamic variable and content ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

i have a list of projects, each have one tag :

project 1 : tag : Home

project 2 : tag : Appartement

...

And i want to be able to display only projects who includes one selected tag

If i put a tag it's working :

```
<% if (project.tags.includes('Appartements')) { %>
    <h2 class="project-title"><%= project.title %></h2>
<%}%>
```

But i want to use button to change this tag :

```
<button onclick="changeSelectedTag('Appartements')">Appartements </button>
<button onclick="changeSelectedTag('Maisons')">Maisons </button>


<script type="text/javascript">
    changeSelectedTag = function(tag) {
        selectedTag = tag;
        console.log(selectedTag)
    }
</script>
```

The console log is working, i can see the selectedTag updated each time i press a button.
but i i put this code, i have 0 projects and selectedTag is empty :

```
<% if (project.tags.includes(selectedTag)) { %>
```

FullCode :

```
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="body-tags">
        <%selectedTag = 'Appartements'%> 
        <button onclick="changeSelectedTag('Appartements')">Appartements</button>
        <button onclick="changeSelectedTag('Maisons')">Maisons</button>
    </div>
    <div class="projects-container">
        <% projects.forEach((project) => { %>

        <% if (project.tags.includes(selectedTag)) { %>
            <div class="projects-content">
                <h2 class="project-title"><%= project.title %></h2>
            </div>
            <%}%>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    changeSelectedTag = function(tag) {
        selectedTag = tag;
        console.log(selectedTag)
    }
</script>
```

RENDER in my controller

```
exports.list = (req, res) => Project.find((err, projects) => {
  if (err) return next(err);
  let selectedTag;
  return res.render('../templates/projects.ejs', { projects: projects, selectedTag: selectedTag });
});
```

CONTENT i want to display :

```
<div id="here" class="items-container">
                <% projects.forEach((project) => { %>
                <%selectedTag = 'Appartements'%>
                <% if (project.tags.includes(selectedTag)) { %>
                    <div class="items-content">
                        <img onmouseover="onProjectHover('<%=project.id%>-img', '<%=project.id%>-titles')"  class="item-img" src="/<%=project.images.main.url%>" alt="<%=project.images.main.alt%>">
                        <div onmouseleave="onProjectLeave('<%=project.id%>-img', '<%=project.id%>-titles')" id="<%=project.id%>-img" class="item-hover-content">
                            <div class="item-hover-content-title">Surface : <span class="item-hover-content-value"><%=project.surface%> m2</span></div>
                            <div class="item-hover-content-title">Budget : <span class="item-hover-content-value"><%=project.budgect%></span></div>
                            <div class="item-hover-content-title">Durée : <span class="item-hover-content-value"><%=project.duration%> mois</span></div>
                            <button class="item-hover-content-btn"><a href="<%=project.slug%>">Voir le projet <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="<%=project.id%>-titles" class="item-titles">
                            <h2 class="item-title"><%= project.title %></h2>
                            <p class="item-city"><%= project.cities %></p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <%}%>
                <% }); %>
            </div>
```

Comment: You need to re-render the template if you change the state of data passed to it originally.

Comment: @Cue thanks :) i edit my post to add my controller where i render my page, any ideas because i'm a little lost for the rendering?

Comment: When you say "controller", to what are you referring to? Is this an express controller?

Comment: Yes i'm rendering my js file in my serverside

Comment: And yeah it's a express controller @Cue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ejs code works. I use pure javascript. You can also use jquery.

```html
<div class="body-content">
  <div class="body-tags">
    <button id='Appartements' onclick="changeSelectedTag('Appartements',<%=JSON.stringify(projects)%>)">Appartements</button>
    <button onclick="changeSelectedTag('Maisons',<%=JSON.stringify(projects)%>)">Maisons</button>

  </div>
  <div id='here' class="projects-container"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  changeSelectedTag = function(tag, projects) {
    selectedTag = tag;
    console.log(selectedTag);
    var main = document.getElementById('here');
    main.innerHTML = '';
    console.log(projects);
    projects.forEach(el => {
      if (el.tags.includes(selectedTag)) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'projects-content';
        var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
        h2.className = 'project-title';
        h2.innerHTML = el.title;
        div.appendChild(h2);
        main.appendChild(div);
      }

    });

  }
  document.getElementById('Appartements').click();
  //changeSelectedTag('Appartements',<%=JSON.stringify(projects)%>);
</script>
```

Comment: hi @tuhin47, i got this error :

list:307 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at changeSelectedTag (list:307)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (list:53)

it say that project is undefined, maybe it's the stringify

Comment: is your data came to ejs properly?

Comment: check using console.log

Comment: In the console i have the changes, but i want to show only the projects with the selected tags

Comment: probably you don't set the `id='Appartements'` or `id='here'` properly

Comment: It work @tuhin47 but i can see only one project .. any ideas?

Comment: The console log show something like 10 projects but the . foreach just run one time

Comment: Yes, I do understand the problem. I have edited my code. Now it works. Please try.

Comment: perfect thanks you very much !  i have just a last question about the content : i edited my post to add the content i want to show, can i render this in my script or i have to do it in javascrip ..? because for the moment i just have the titles included in the script and i can't see all my content in the div with the 'here' id

Comment: in this process you  can create element as like i create h2 in javascript. btw if the answer is correct don't forget to mark it correct :)

Comment: Ok so i have to do all with appendchild and create element in js ? @tuhin47

Comment: okey, i mean i will try but like a post my code in my question i have somes onmouseover="onProjectHover" etc...